# I am trying to translate the song "tsukihana," but I am confused by this line: 罪を灯しひなぎくの 夢に寄り添う爪の痕

Tags: translation

As the title says, I am translating tsukihana, but I can't come up with a nice way to translate the above line. If anyone has any ideas, that would be helpful. A Japanese friend said it was like a metaphor, but couldn't provide me with an explanation.

Here are the full song lyrics for context:
http://www.kasi-time.com/item-40184.html

> 闇と玩(あそ)ぶ星たちへ
>   愛を唄い焼き尽くして
>
> **罰を灯しひなぎくの**
>   **夢に寄り添う爪の痕**
>
> 唇から 唇へと伝い
>   その温もりは何処へ?
>   たどり着く宛は無いのに
>
> 貴方でなくちゃ満たせない
>   私じゃなきゃ許せなかった
>   だから私はこの脚で
>   立ち上がれてぞっとしたんだ
>
> 飼い殺しなら救われる
>   でも見事に鍵は外れて
>   私はまるで
>   鳥籠を欲している狂った小鳥
>
> 嘘を抱いた華

Here is what I have so far:

> To the stars that flirt with darkness
>
> I sing of love and burn to nothing
>
> Daisies light up their punishments
>
> Nails cuddle up, marking your dreams
>
> My lips follow yours
>
> Where has that warmth gone
>
> Even though it has nowhere to go?
>
> Only you can satisfy my heart
>
> Only I could have allowed you to
>
> So with these legs
>
> I stood up shaking
>
> If you keep me as a pet until I die, I'll be saved
>
> Yet, when the lock opened,
>
> It's like I’m a small crazy bird
>
> That longs for its own cage
>
> The flower that holds lies

Comment: You should add your "try" on the translation, or it will be set as off topic

Answer (score 1):

爪の痕 or 爪痕 is a set phrase/word that means scratch scar.

Needless to say, the line is figurative and vague, but it's even grammatically ambiguous to me. Especially I'm not sure what 罰を灯し is doing here.

> 1. ( 罰を灯し、ひなぎくの夢に寄り添う→) 爪の痕
>    A scratch scar that lights the punishment and cuddles up to the dream of the daisy.
> 2. ( ( ( 罰を灯し**し**→) ひなぎくの夢) に寄り添う→) 爪の痕
>    A scratch scar that cuddles up to the dream of the daisy that lit the punishment.
>
> (Arrows indicate a relative clause)

Technically, only the first interpretations is possible. The second interpretation is not possible without adding an extra し, which is the attributive form of the [archaic past auxiliary き](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009002.htm). As long as we can believe this sentence is grammatical, it's the scar, not the daisy, that is "lighting the punishment".

As for the interpretation, this ひなぎく is obviously the metaphor for "I", the person in despair. After this part, there are lines which clearly say "I'm like a small bird." So the basic implication of the lines should be "the scratch scar is illuminating (my?) guilt and is always with my dream" or even more simply, "something ominous is haunting me."